# how to execute a python file in system

Tags: python, file, directory

I have a python script file which is used to rename files under a specific folder. How can I execute this python file so that I can change my filenames in a folder?

part of my code is as follow

```
import os
os.system()
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    oldfile = [val for val in filename if val in oldname] 
    if filename==oldfile:
        os.rename(filename,newname)
```

Comment: So, you can write Python code, but can't _run_ it?? Please consult the official site of Python, which has great docs on this topic.

Comment: Specify your operating system. Also, your script has a lot of errors e.g. undefined variables like oldname, newname, no arguments passed to os.system(), etc

Answer (score 0):

```
python filename.py
```

This on your terminal, if you have python installed properly.